# Calculate a given hard integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Calculate:
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{1 + x^4}}{1 - x^4} dx$$

I've been thinking about a good substitution, but I haven't found any yet. Integration by parts doesn't gave me anything meaningful.

Thank you!

Comment: [According to WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(sqrt(1%2Bx%5E4))%2F(x%5E4-1)+dx), it seems that your integral cannot be computed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: this integral leads to an elliptc integral

Comment: do you need the solution?

Comment: Yes, I need a way to calculate it.

Comment: @GeorgeR.: If you need to calculate it, you can use the form given by Wolfram Alpha. Lots of numerical packages support various hypergeometric functions. Alternatively, you could just quadrature to compute the integral directly.

Comment: @Crostul: There is an elementary form; see the duplicate that I've linked to.